# How can I get the text after one character in a String in Java

Tags: java, string

I have the next String:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: User not found
```

I want to get the next String
starting from the previous:

```
User not found
```

How can I get that using JDK 7?. The "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:" its the same always

Comment: Is the string always *exactly* like this, or can it change? If so, what is the expected structure of the String?

Comment: A simple `.split(": ")` might be all that is needed, no?

Comment: The "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:" its the same always

Comment: I think you could be solving the wrong problem.  If you have the exception object (e.g. because you *caught* it), you can get the `"User not found"` message (or whatever) by calling `getMessage()` on the exception object.

Answer (score -1):

```
String myString ="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: User not found";

myString=myString.replace("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:","");
```

Comment: Ughhh.  There are better ways.   Hint: use `substring(...)`.